# Read text file and take region names in Python

Tags: python

Have a text file that is to be read then I need to take the names under "Region" and place them in a list which I'm having trouble as with my code it only takes one word from the "Region" instead of the full name of the region due to my split, but I can't find a way to figure it out.

An example of the text file first 2 entries. I want to add "GULF OF CALIFORNIA" and "OFF THE EAST COAST OF HONSHU" as one item to the list but my code only adds "CALIFORNIA" or "JAPAN" to the list.

```
         MAG        UTC DATE-TIME           LAT       LON       DEPTH    Region

    MAP  4.3    2014/03/12 20:16:59       25.423     -109.730   10.0     GULF OF CALIFORNIA
    MAP  5.2    2014/03/12 20:09:55       36.747      144.050   24.2     OFF THE EAST COAST OF HONSHU, JAPAN
```

```
def main(): #defining main function
    magList = [] #magnitude list of all together
    regionList = [] #creating list to hold region names
    newRegionList = []
    with open("earthquakes.txt", "r") as eqList: #opens earthquake text file and gets the magnitudes
        eqList.readline()
        for line in eqList:
            line = line.split()
            magList.append(float(line[1])) #appends magnitude as float values in list

    with open("earthquakes.txt", "r") as eqList2:
            eqList2.readline()
            for line in eqList2:
                line = line.split()
                regionList.append(line[-1])
    newRegionList = list(set(regionList))

    greatMag = [] #creating lists for different category magnitudes
    majorMag = []
    strongMag = []
    moderateMag = []

    for x in magList: #conditions for seperating magnitude
        if x >= 8:
            greatMag.append(x)
        elif  7 <= x <= 7.9:
            majorMag.append(x)
        elif 6 <= x <= 6.9:
            strongMag.append(x)
        elif 5 <= x <= 5.9:
            moderateMag.append(x)

    print(greatMag)
    print()
    print(majorMag)
    print()    
    print(strongMag)
    print()
    print(moderateMag)
    print()
    print(regionList)


if __name__ == "__main__": #runs main function
    main()
```

After running my code it adds "CALIFORNIA" and "JAPAN" to the list, but I need the whole region name instead of just the last word of the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
line = line.split()
line = line[0:7] + [" ".join(line[7:])]
```

A simple method is to merge together anything at the tail end of the list.

You can also do this by limiting the number of splits returned. Since you're splitting on multiple whitespace, you need to use the regular expression splitter instead of the string splitter:

```
import re
re.split('\s+', line, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks figured it out didn't need to import a module I simply just adjusted the join line and got the output I needed